# Passing values in Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am very new to MVC and have Novice's knowledge about MVC.
I am creating an MVC application, where I have this page which displays Events taking place in a particular time.
Now when I select the event from the drop-down list, I get the specific event's details. Now along with that specific event's description, I need to get the feedback people has entered for that specific event.
Here is my View :

```
<div><a href="<%:Url.Action("ManagementHome","Home")%>">Home </a>>> Events</div>
<br /> 
<%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.Event)%> 
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Event.SelectedValue, Model.Event.GetSelectList(), new {    id = "EventDropDown"})%>
<br /><br /> 
<div id="result" style="color: Green; border: 1px null transparent; ">
<%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViews/EventsPartial.ascx"); %>
</div> 
<%:Ajax.ActionLink("view", "viewFeedback", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "comments" }, new {eventid=Model.Event.SelectedValue})%>

<div id="comments" style="color: Green; border: 1px null transparent;">
<%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViews/FeedbackPartial.ascx"); %>
</div>
```

Can anyone please suggest how do I pass that event's ID in its ActionLink?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have to use ajax function for this:

```
  $('youractionlinkid').click(function () {
          var id = $('#yourdropdownid').val();
         $.ajax({
             url: this.href,
             type: 'GET',
             data: { id:id },
             cache: false,
             success: function (result) {
                 //do some action here
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass values with `Html.ActionLink` using `routeValues` in the parameter.

For example:

```
// VB
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "MyAction", New With {.eventId = 1})

// C#
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "MyAction", new {eventId = 1})
```

Might produce the link:

```
http://localhost/MyAction?eventId=1
```

Comment: But that would be hard-coded.
Can we get something like- as we select the value from drop-down, it will take the 'eventId' automatically?

Comment: Absolutely, but without seeing your code I cannot program that for you.

Comment: I have posted my View's code, of what I am trying to do. Please suggest me how do I bind my dropdown selected value into html.actionink..

Answer (score 0):

Razor will take AJAX this way also:

```
<div class="editorholder">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Display_ID, new SelectList(Model._listAllDisplayViewModel.ListAllDisplayInfo, "DisplayID", "DisplayName"), "Select.....", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DisplayID", @onchange = "DisplayInfo();" })
</div>




<div class="editor-field">
  <div id="DisplayView">
    @Html.Partial("_DisplayView", Model._displayViewModel)
  </div>
 </div>




function DisplayInfo() {
    $("#DisplayView").load('@(Url.Action("_DisplayView", "Display", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?id=' + $("#DisplayID").val());
};
```